# Android application starts from wrong activity & unable to upload image to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

First of all, sorry for any misunderstanding, typos since english is not my native language. I'm trying to write my first app in Android Studio.

What my app does: ( at least '' should do '' ) :

1 : User Login Screen as MainActivity
2 : if user credientals is true, user is directed to 2nd screen which is Request form.
3 : User puts his name-surname,subject,and explanation of subject.

4 : User CAN also upload pictures from imagebutton. it's not necessary.
5,6,7.... : this parts will be added to program. for now it's only 4 steps :D

Now my problems,
1 : When i run the app it starts from request form(2nd activity) even i clean project before running.
2 : When user type some input for name-surname,object and explanation and click send button, infos are stored in firebase database. But when i select an image for imagebutton it doesnt get stored in firebase. All authentication are set.

**LOGIN SCREEN CODE**

```
 package com.example.jalea.requestingform;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edt_email,edt_sifre;
    Button bt_giris;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        edt_sifre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sifre);
        bt_giris = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_giris);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RequestActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //finish();
                    Log.w("1 : ","2.activity'e geçildi");
                }
                else{
                    Log.w("1 : ", "onAuthStateChanged:çıkış yaptı");
                }
            }
        };
        bt_giris.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SignIn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(authStateListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        }
    }
    public void SignIn(){
        String email = edt_email.getText().toString();
        String sifre = edt_sifre.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(sifre)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Kullanıcı adı veya şifre alanı boş",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,sifre).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatası ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    /**if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RequestActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);**/


                }
            });
        }



    }
}
```

**REQUEST FORM CODE**

```
package com.example.jalea.requestingform;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class RequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    Button btn_cikis,btn_gonder;
    ImageButton imgbutton;
    EditText et_isim,et_konu,et_aciklama;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    Uri uri=null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_request);
        btn_cikis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cikis);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        et_isim= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_isim);
        et_konu= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_konu);
        et_aciklama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        btn_gonder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Send);
        btn_cikis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(RequestActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
        btn_gonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String isim = et_isim.getText().toString();
                String konu = et_konu.getText().toString();
                String aciklama = et_aciklama.getText().toString();
                Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
                databaseReference = database.getReference("Kullanicilar").child(isim);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(isim) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(konu) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(aciklama)) {
                    databaseReference.child("adSoyad").setValue(isim);
                    databaseReference.child("Konu").setValue(konu);
                    databaseReference.child("Aciklama").setValue(aciklama);
                    Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, "Talep gönderildi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Resim").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                    filePath.putFile(uri)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                    Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, "Resim eklendi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                    filePath.putFile(uri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w("İmage hata : ", e);
                        }
                    });

                }



            }

        });

    }

    public void imageButtonClicked(View View){
        Intent gallery_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        gallery_intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(gallery_intent,2);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            uri = data.getData();
            imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imgbutton.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jalea.requestingform">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RequestActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you want to go to second activity when user clicks on button and if the firebase returns success ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But app starts from 2nd activity. I had to put an logout button to 2nd activity to see if login screen works properly.When logout button clicked, it directs user to login screen. But not in the start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app bypasses the MainActivity since you have this the following code:

```
 authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RequestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
                Log.w("1 : ","2.activity'e geçildi");
            }
            else{
                Log.w("1 : ", "onAuthStateChanged:çıkış yaptı");
            }
        }
    };
```

That code checks to see if the user is logged in and then skips the MainActivity and goes straight to RequestActivity. If you want the user to log in every time he/she opens the app then remove that code.

For your second problem, check out this sample code:

```
    private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Posting... ");


    final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString();
    final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString();
    final String cat_val = mPostCat.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String currency_val = mPostCurrency.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String amount_val = mPostAmount.getText().toString();
    final String offer_val = mPostOffer.getText().toString();
    final String pNumber_val = mPostPNumber.getText().toString();



    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(cat_val)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(currency_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(amount_val) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(offer_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pNumber_val) && mImageUri != null ){

        mProgress.show();

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Classifieds_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                final Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();



                mDatabaseUsers.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        newPost.child("name").setValue(title_val);
                        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                        newPost.child("category").setValue(cat_val);
                        newPost.child("currency").setValue(currency_val);
                        newPost.child("amount").setValue(amount_val);
                        newPost.child("offer").setValue(offer_val);
                        newPost.child("phone number").setValue(pNumber_val);
                        newPost.child("latitude").setValue(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
                        newPost.child("longitude").setValue(mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                        newPost.child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                        newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                        newPost.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                        newPost.child("profileImage").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("profile_image").getValue());
                        newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                mProgress.dismiss();




            }
        });

    }
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                mImageUri = data.getData();
                mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

                CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .start(this);
            }


            break;

        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                mImageUri = data.getData();
                activity(mImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .start(this);
                mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

            }
            break;
    }


    if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        ActivityResult result = getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = result.getUri();

            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        } else if (resultCode == CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}



private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            PostActivity.this);


    builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePicture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);}

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For first :

It will start from your second activity only since you have written this

```
  if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RequestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish(); 
                Log.w("1 : ","2.activity'e geçildi");
            }
```

For sure reason you might have done sign in and its stores the auth to let the user directly go to next activity

For your second issue I am able to do it like this

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if (requestCode == ConstantsCustomGallery.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ConstantsCustomGallery.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        boolean showMinMax = true;
        final MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Please wait")
                .content("This won't take too long")
                .progress(false, images.size(), showMinMax)
                .show();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(i).path));
            StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            String Fpath = getFileName(uri) ;

            //Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
            StorageReference riversRef = storage.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()+"/images/"+Fpath);


            riversRef.putFile(uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            int maxUploading = dialog.getMaxProgress();
                            dialog.incrementProgress(1);
                            if(dialog.getCurrentProgress() == dialog.getMaxProgress()){
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                new MaterialDialog.Builder(HomePageActivity.this)
                                        .title("DONE")
                                        .content("Congratulations")

                                        .show();
                            }
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            String key = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();
                            Map<String, Object> postValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            postValues.put("/user-profile/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()
                                    .substring(0, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().indexOf("@"))+"/user-images/"+key,downloadUrl.toString());
                            postValues.put("/user-profile/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()
                                    .substring(0, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().indexOf("@"))+"/imagesuploaded/",maxUploading);
                            mDatabase.updateChildren(postValues);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                        }
                    });

        }
        dialog.setContent("Hurray!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How should i change my code to start from login screen? Where should i put my intent to prevent from starting 2nd activity?

Answer (score 0):

For launching the app from the activity you want, enter below code in manifest.xml file for the activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="SpinnerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Everything is same except mine doesnt have  android:screenOrientation="portrait" . I still added it but it doesnt work